# jQuery - growlUI Notification using screen scraped tweet

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, growl

I am trying to pull my latest tweet into a variable in javascript, then use growlUI() to display this in a notification in jQuery.

Currently, I have pulled my tweet using PHP into a variable in javascript called test. I need to adjust the following jQuery code to use "test" instead of "Hello".

Current code works:

```
$.growlUI('Growl Notification','Hello');
```

Attempted code does not work:

```
$.growlUI('Growl Notification', $(test));
```

**My Question**

**How do I use the variable test, which is a javascript variable, as a jQuery attribute?**

Many thanks!

My source code:

```
<html>

<head>

    <!-- Styling for growlUI -->
<style type="text/css">
    div.growlUI { background: url(check48.png) no-repeat 10px 10px }
    div.growlUI h1, div.growlUI h2 {
    color: white; padding: 5px 5px 5px 75px; text-align: left
}
</style>

<!-- Import jquery from online -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Import blockUI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">

<!-- Screenscrape using PHP, put into javascript variable 'test' -->

    <?php

    $url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=XXXXXXXXXX";
    $raw = file_get_contents($url);
    $newlines = array("\t","\n","\r","\x20\x20","\0","\x0B");
    $content = str_replace($newlines, "", html_entity_decode($raw));

    $start = strpos($content,'<text>');
    $end = strpos($content,'</text>',$start);
    $latesttweet = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);

    echo "var test = ".$latesttweet.";\n";

    ?>

</script>

</head>

<!-- Here I'm attempting to use test variable in second half of growlUI parameters -->
<body onLoad="$.growlUI('Latest Update',test); ">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly does the variable `test` contain? Is it the string version of the tweet? And are you just trying to pass that string into the growlUI function?

Comment: It's the String version of the tweet. Basically, I can right click on my page and see the following in the source:                               <script type = "text/javascript">
 var test = <text>TWEET HERE</text>.
</script>
 I'll remove the HTML tags later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is your problem, but it looks like your js string variable is not quoted:

```
echo "var test = ".$latesttweet.";\n";
```

Should be:

```
echo "var test = '".$latesttweet."';\n";
```

You should probably escape .$latesttweet to handle apostrophes.

Comment: Doh! The single quotes were required to make it work. What a mistake... Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable `test` that is a string tweet, and you want to pass that string into your growlUI function...just do it:

```
var test = "my string blah";
$.growlUI('Growl Notification', test);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I can do:                   $.growlUI('Growl Notification', 'test');                                       but not:                                                                        $.growlUI('Growl Notification', test);                                        I'll post my full source code above, it's pretty simple bar this part.